# Why is the definition of sin and cos in terms of exponentials is similar to the definition of $L_x$ & $L_y$ in terms of raising & lowering operators?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function, quantum-mechanics

I noted a similarity outlined below:

The angular momentum operators in $x$ and $y$ direction can be written:

$$L_x=\frac{1}{2}(L_++L_-)$$
$$L_y=\frac{1}{2i}(L_+-L_-)$$

$cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$ can be written:

$$\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$$
$$\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$$

Is there a particular reason for this manifest similarity, or it is just a mere coincidence, without much depth in it?

---

*Note: this question has been asked here as well: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/466480/212053*

Comment: Related: [Is there any underlying relationship between an even function and a symmetric matrix , as well as an odd function and a skew symmetric matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2907087/856)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the inverse relation; 
$$
L_x+iL_y=L_+, \qquad L_x-iL_y=L_-, $$
and compare it with 
$$
x+iy=z, \qquad x-iy=\overline z.$$
With $x=\cos \theta, y=\sin \theta$, you have the analogy you spotted.

---

You ask why such relations are useful. The reason is that they massively simplify the description of plane rotations, because they reduce them to multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$.

More precisely, if we let
$$
W:=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ 1 & -i\end{bmatrix},$$
then we can compactly write the above formulas in matrix form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}L_+ \\ L_-\end{bmatrix} =  W \begin{bmatrix} L_x \\ L_y\end{bmatrix}. $$
And now we notice that, for $\theta\in\mathbb R$,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}e^{i\theta}L_+ \\ e^{-i\theta}L_-\end{bmatrix} = W \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} L_x \\ L_y\end{bmatrix}.$$
This is the simplification we were talking about: the linear change of variable induced by $W$ conjugates a rotation matrix to multiplication by $e^{\pm i \theta}$. This also explains the subscripts $\pm$ in $L_+, L_-$.

Comment: Yes, this is a bit better than my original formulas, though still leaves me wondering if there is a deeper relation between the two (either considered in the form of the OP or this answer), or just simply algebraic accident.

Comment: You will always find something like this; given two real quantities, such as $x$ and $y$, you form a single complex one. You will then have to consider both this quantity and its conjugate as independent. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2501826/8157)'s a good answer describing a rather general appearance of this trick.

Comment: @zabop: I corrected and expanded the post. It was wrong before, as I had suppressed what is now called "the matrix $W$".